# preferred way to make a unique column id in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi all I just wanted to know if there is a preferred way of creating a unique id within a sql table so far I have tried `Auto-increment` of the number and this started to cause problems in future planning, so I have thought about using the php `Rand()` and then turning this into a string and then insert this into a database but there is a higher chance off two numbers being the same with the amount of data that will be within the database.

I was just wondering if there any suggestions of a preferred way to create a unique column_id
im open to all suggestions there is just a couple things the id needs to be easy enough to be used within other tables within inner joins and left outer joins and also used a file name as well for a download section and a upload section.

Comment: *have tried Auto-increment of the number and this started to cause problems in future planning* what's the problem?

Comment: Sequence is an alternative.

Comment: @StanislavL A partner that I am working with has created the same type of project that we are currently working on and he found that there restrictions from using an auto increment so to lower the chances of this happening again we decided to use a unique number or mix of number and letters or anything else like date and time. it is mainly problems like user uploading things at the same time and then the sql trying to give the same number to each so we though it would be easier to use a unique id to prevent this

Comment: @NavjotSingh what do you mean by sequence could you clarify is it a sql type or php function. any documentation would be much appreciated

Comment: @user3387522 Please see
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/rdb/0307-sequences-130053.pdf

Comment: @NavjotSingh im just wondering is this able to work within a phpmyadmin database or not I'm not to familiar with Oracle Rdb or would this need to be done within a oracle database ?

Comment: Sequence is an Oracle object. So it needs to be used within the Oracle database. Not sure if MySql or other dbs offer a similar object.

Comment: @NavjotSingh thats ok we have decided what database we will be using so we may pick to go down the oracle root just wondering do you know any other options either in oracle databases or others

Comment: @user3387522 Sequences are specifically designed for this feature and they were the de facto standard at my workplace. For Oracle, sequence would be the way to go. My experience with databases is limited to Oracle, So cannot comment for other dbs.

Comment: @NavjotSingh That's great thank you we are strongly considering this option =D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
 echo uniqid();
?>
```

[Description](https://www.php.net/uniqid)

Comment: Would there be a way to shorten this due to the id having to be the same as the file name that it needs to be linked to and that seems to be a little long for say a PDF document @SagarPanchal

Comment: you can split this result from the start but it not good idea

Comment: is there a way to limit how many characters long can it be for example Min_length or Max_Length or any thing like that

Answer (score 2):

use GUID

```
string com_create_guid ( void )
```

Comment: Thanks for that it looks interesting i believe someone mentioned it to me when i started to research on this topic i found this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php)
but i was just wondering what could the outcomes be for a GUID do you know any examples that show the out put of the GUID

Comment: GUID looks like this: 25892e17-80f6-415f-9c65-7395632f0223 It's unique identifier that builds by special algorithms. Generated value depends of time when it was generated, PC on which it was generated and so on. The best thing of GUID - it is unique. Always. There is no any chance that will be generated two equal GUIDs. [more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Comment: just wondering off the top of your head do you know if you can set how many characters there are for GUID or is there a static amount.

Comment: Amount of characters in GUID is always static.

Comment: Thank you for the information I could not find the information you have been a big help